# Spring MongoTemplate atPosition() not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring MongoTemplate to store documents on mongodb which contain an array of documents that need to be constantly added.

Since I want to be able to look up the newest array elements first, I want to insert new array elements at the beginning of the array. This is supposedly possible using the $position operator, so I tried writing this query:

```
    final Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(docId));
    Update update = new Update().push("docArray").atPosition(0).value(arrayElement);

    mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, new FindAndModifyOptions().upsert(true), 
            MyDocument.class, mongoDBConfig.MY_COLLECTION);
```

The arrayElement object gets successfully inserted to the array, but it is placed at the last position instead of the first as I was expecting.

While I do see the "$position" Update$PositionModifier in the pushCommandBuilders modifier list when inspecting the Update object, I do not see the operator added to the mappedUpdate DBObject when trying to execute the update query. I also tried using `.atPosition(Position.FIRST)` instead, but it produces the same result.

After reading some more, I realized that the mongodb documentation states that the $position modifier must be used together with the $each modifier (for whatever reason), so I tried this instead:

```
Update update = new Update().push("docArray").atPosition(0).each(arrayElement);
```

This time it produced this query for the mappedUpdate DBObject: `{ "$push" : { "docArray" : { "$position" : 0 , "$each" : [ {"object"}]}}}` , which instead of adding the array element at the first position, it just treated the query modifiers as if they were fields of the arrayElement object and produced this instead:

```
{
  "_id" : "id",
  "docArray" : 
    [
      ...
     ,{"$position" : 0,
         "$each" : [{arrayElement}]
      }
    ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug with MongoTemplate? I'm aware there are other ways to get the newest array items first, but this approach seemed the most efficient, so I'd like to use it if possible.

Comment: Have you filed a bug report or found a solution?

Comment: Not yet. Where might I file a bug report?